# Show particular image in SecondActivity by clicking particular Button in FirstActivity

Tags: android, button, android-intent, imageview

I am in developing an Android Application as a beginner which has two `Activities`,
Title `FirstActivity`, `SecondActivity`.
`FirstActivity` has two `Buttons` name `France`, `Canada`.
`SecondActivity` is for showing the flag of each country by clicking the `Button` and it has `ImageView`.
if click `France` `button` shows the flag of France in `SecondActivity`. Likewise `Canada Button`.

Basically, What I asked, the SecondActivity should show the images based on which Button is clicked in FirstActivity.

Comment: where you put 2 images? In drawables, mipmap, raw folder or assets.

Comment: What is a problem? what stops you from doing that?

Comment: @DINITHRUKSHANKUMARA put in drawable

Comment: @duggu


its not a duplicate question which you said,

Comment: @M.Bavatharany

i'm unable to post answer so i give suggestion 


first when click on any  button pass string in bundle in intent

then in second activity check that string and compare it then change flag or image programmatically

Comment: @Adil can u elaborate how ?

Comment: yes, which question you mark as a duplicate it says pass selected image from one screen to another , and here on button click we need to manage flag and using flag change image from DRAW-ABLE to second screen which i  suggest in my above comment